# How to know if a uitableview section is visible after user scrolls the table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped UI tableview, which has a lot of sections. The table cells  are loaded from a json data response. However, due to the number of rows in the sections and the grouped cells i would like to reduce the number sql queries currently required to load the data, which taking 8-12 seconds, Instead i want to implement something similar to the infinite scrolling techniques used on web applications, but in my case i will have tables with emtpy content except for the table section header, and when the section comes into the middle point of the view i would like to show a loader in that section and then dynamically load that data into the table. Also is it possible that there could be more than one async request as the user may scroll past a section, which will then call the method to load the next section.

I am very new to ios and objective-c and finding it difficult to find in the apple documentation and in SO or google for a similar feature.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this link will help u 
 http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/8-automatic-uitableview-paging

Answer (score 0):

I think the Situation you are talking about is Pagination in technical terms.

and for pagination u can find many solution.
here is one of them solution u can implement

```
  @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isLoading;
```

/**
 *  Set this flag if more data can be loaded.
 */

```
   @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL hasNextPage;
```

/**
 *  The current page loaded from the server. Used for pagination.
 */

```
 @property (assign, nonatomic) int currentPage;

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Check scrolled percentage
//
CGFloat yOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y;
CGFloat height = tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat scrolledPercentage = yOffset / height;


// Check if all the conditions are met to allow loading the next page
//
if (scrolledPercentage > .6f && !self.isLoading && self.hasNextPage)
    [self loadNextPage:++self.currentPage];}

 - (void)loadNextPage:(int)pageNumber 

{
if (self.isLoading) return;
self.isLoading = YES;

// Fetch your data here
// ..

// Once the request is finished, call this
self.isLoading = NO;

 }
```

Comment: Kavita, Thank you for reply.The willDisplayCell is the correct method i was looking, although my requirment is not entirely like table pagination, as there is sections in the the view, i am able to access i the section is in view and then apply my method which i need to load the data for that section. The only thing i am stuck with not is how add a loader icon for each section specifically when there is no table rows for a section which i am going to be loading dyanmically